# Create options list for react Select from single dimension array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array like [ 123, 456 ] and it needs to be mapped into a react Select with label and value pairs so the "options" will be:
0: {label: "123", value: 123}
1: {label: "456", value: 456}

I just can't seem to get the map syntax to work for the source array (i.e. 0: 123, 1: 456)

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
array.map((item)=> <Option label={item} value={item}/>)
```

This return an array of holding options with your label and value

Answer (score 1):

If you need the options array you can write this:

```
let Myarray= [ 123, 456 ];
Myarray.map((item)=> <Option label={item} value={item}/>)
```

or If you need an array with label and value:

```
let Myarray= [ 123, 456 ];
let FinalArray=[];
Myarray.map((item)=>[...FinalArray,{label:item,value:item}])
```

if you want to put " to value

```
let Myarray= [ 123, 456 ];
let FinalArray=[];
Myarray.map((item)=>[...FinalArray,{label:item.toString(),value:item}])
```

Comment: Your answer is closest to what I need. However it does not create a proper "options" array to pass to the react <Select. Each value is an array itself. My code is:  console.log(this.props.buildingUnits);
    let options = [];
    options = this.props.buildingUnits.map((item) => (
      [...options, { label: item, value: item }]
    ));
    console.log(options);
~~~~ eslint pitches a fit if I try and alter it. I think the label value needs double quote around it.
[Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), …]

0
:
[{…}]

0
:
{label: 101, value: 101}

Comment: btw, there is another select list on the form and it contains these values and I just can't get the buildingUnits array to have this form: options
:
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]

0: {label: "Acura", value: 143}

Comment: please, share your code in the question

Comment: Arash, many thanks for your help. I have this part working now with this code: let apartments = [];
    apartments = this.props.buildingUnits.map((item) => (
      { label: item, value: item }
    )); It still does not have double-quotes around the label: item so it has the form 0: { label: "123", value: 123 }. The syntax to surround item with those quotes eludes me, but the select list does display the proper labels.

Comment: I edit my answer last part explains how to add a string to your object

Comment: label:item.toString()